# Sort array of struct based on single/multiple dynamic struct fields

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, linked-list, user-input

My struct is the following:

```
typedef struct cellular_phone{
    int id;
    char name[40];
    int ram;
    char cpu[20];
    int display_ppi;
    double display_size;
    char display_resolution[10];
    char size[15];
    int weight;
    char notes[500];
    int id_manufacturer;
    int id_os;
}phone;
```

I am trying to give the user the ability to sort an array of such structs based on his field/s of choosing; for example: sort by id_os and if equal sort for name
The algorithm I want to use is c's qsort().

I thought that a possible way of implementing this would be by creating a function for each type and using a chain of if/elses to check the user input. Obviously this would be extremelly inefficient and would be almost impossible to use with multiple fields.
C also does not support reflection so even comparing the user input against struct members is not possible.

I am pretty new to C so I do not know if this way of doing things is correct and I'm open for suggestions

Comment: *"Obviously this would be extremelly inefficient and would be almost impossible to use with multiple fields"* **???????** that's about as most efficient as you can get.

Comment: Considering that there are 12 fields in the struct, 12 functions would need to be created only to support basic cases. If the user wants to sort by 2 fields that would lead to a large amount of functions, thus making this solution unreasonable.

Comment: Ah, I see you meant a function *per field*. That's not needed. What is needed is a function for the type of object you want to order (in this case your type is `struct cellular_phone`), and that function can check all the fields with a series of if/else when needed. This is the way `qsort` is intended to be used.

Comment: I think the best you can do is to create 12 comparison functions which you'll need to pass to your qs function as argument. All these 12 functions would take 2 `struct cellular_phone`s parameters and would return an int representing the comparison result.